# Add Visual Studio Web to Visual Studio Desktop

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I just wanted to start learing WCF and could not find the `WCF Service Library` in my `Visual Studio 2012 Windows Desktop`. After reading and searching I found out that I need the `VS Web` to get access to it. Since I try to avoid installing two versions of VS I wat to ask if it is possible to add `VS Web` to `VS Desktop`.

Comment: You will have to install Web version too. But we should not complain, both are for free.

Comment: If I want to develop Desktop Applicatins (with access to web services), can I do that in the Web Version? I thought I need the WCF Service Lib in the Desktop Version.

Comment: You can add service reference in the Desktop version. To develop this service you will need Web version.

Comment: As an update - there is now free, new version of Visual Studio - which supports different versions in one solution - [Visual Studio Community](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)